# Set backcolor for specific cell in gridview in VB.net Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, cell, backcolor

I have a fixed size grid and would like to specify the backcolor of specific cells within the grid, so not whole rows and not whole columns just a single cell or maybe a range of cells. Please see the screenshot below for and example of what I mean.

Ideally I would like to do this via vb as I would ultimately like to alter the backcolor based on values selected from a dropdown list.

[image]

**Edit:**

Based on the answer below I modified it until I got the below which worked.

```
GridView.Rows(n).Cells(n).BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(n, n, n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating a windows forms application, you can use the DataGridView.  It allows individual cells to be styled using the following property:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```